# Validate Data in a CSV file using MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, csv, validation

I am trying to validate the UK phone number contain in a CSV file before inserting the data in the table. At the moment the if statement is not working when the mobile number is valid the code doesn't jump to the else block. See the code below.
Controller code

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken] 
    public async Task<ActionResult>  BulkMEssage(TextMessage messagedetail, 
         HttpPostedFileBase attachmentcsv,
        MobileRecipient messagelink, int ddlshedule, string date)
     {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
           {
            CsvFileDescription csvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
            {
              SeparatorChar = ',',
              FirstLineHasColumnNames = true
            };
               CsvContext csvContext = new CsvContext();
               StreamReader streamReader = new 
               StreamReader(attachmentcsv.InputStream);
               IEnumerable<MobileRecipient> list = 
              csvContext.Read<MobileRecipient>(streamReader, 
              csvFileDescription);
         foreach (var mobilenumber in list)
         {
           var phoneno = @"/^ (\+44\s ? 7\d{ 3}|\(? 07\d{ 3}\)?)\s ?\d{ 3}\s ?\d{ 3}$/";
           if ((!mobilenumber.MobileNumber.Equals(phoneno)))
            {
                  error message Here with the wrong format number   
            }
            else
            {
                Insert Data in the database
            }
       }
   }
```

I think I am using the regular expression the wrong way. The column name in my CSV file is called "MobileNumber". Please suggest if you have any better way to do this.

Comment: You need to use [Regex.Match](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twcw2f1c(v=vs.110).aspx) for regular expression match

Comment: You need to use the methods in the `Regex` namespace, for example [Regex.IsMatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y21t6y4(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I added this   if ((mobilenumber.MobileNumber.Regex.IsMatch(phoneno))) but I have the error 'string does not  contain a definition for Regex'. Thanks

Comment: @EricAimeTchatchoua perhaps it is worth following a tutorial to get a better understanding of what you are using https://www.dotnetperls.com/regex